# Code for one-time execution in Arduino

Tags: programming

**Question:** Where do I put code if I want it to execute only once per Arduino startup?

**Background:** I tend to use my Arduino to perform tasks that should be executed once per power cycle.  (For example, my robot should only drive forward *once* every time I turn it on--more than that, and it might fall off the table.)

The standard Arduino IDE "template" consists of a `loop()` and a `setup()` function.  The `setup` code is run once per power cycle, and the `loop` is re-started every time it finishes.

I see two approaches to code "1 time tasks:"

### Method 1: "Loop once"

```
void setup() {
  //do setup stuff
}

void loop() {
  //do task

  while(1) ; //Repeat forever, preventing function from re-starting
}
```

### Method 2: "Setup only"

```
void setup() {
  //do setup stuff

  //do task
}

void loop() {
  //do nothing
}
```

**More detailed form of question:**  Is one of these methods "better" from a hardware/software sense?  (e.g. is there anything "special" about the `setup` function, like it can only run for so much time?)
And, if they are the same from a hardware/software perspective, is there a "best practice" or standard way of writing code for these situations in the Arduino community?

Comment: Some use of the `exit` command is discussed in http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/188/what-happens-when-i-call-exit-from-my-program

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm kind of confused by your question. You ask where you want to put once-per-startup setup functions, and then discuss the setup function. *That's what the setup function is for.*

As such, one-time setup functionality goes in the setup function.

FWIW, if you look in the file that *calls* the `setup` and `loop` functions:

```
#include <Arduino.h>

int main(void)
{
    init();

#if defined(USBCON)
    USBDevice.attach();
#endif

    setup();
    for (;;) {
        loop();
        if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

For all intents and purposes, the two options are completely identical. Either way, you get a empty busy-wait loop. Frankly, I'd expect the two different options to probably emit the same machine code anyways, so the whole thing is a non-issue.

Note:
`if (serialEventRun) serialEventRun();` appears to be a facility to allow you to attach a function that is called upon reception of serial data, but if you do not define a function `void serialEvent(){}` in your code, it will compile out completely and not be present in the produced machine code.

Comment: It feels weird to accept an answer that isn't (yet) the highest-voted.  But, seeing the `main()` function definition was really helpful to my question.  (And, you do indicate a consensus with the group with using `setup` instead of `loop`).  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @anorton - When in doubt, look under the covers. I find the arduino platform convenient for prototyping, but it's largely just boilerplate code. Understanding what it's doing can be tremendously helpful in deciding how to architect something.

Answer (score 6):

I usually go with Method 2, but end up doing this:

```
void setup() {
  //do setup stuff

  //do task
  init(); //Do start-up initialization steps
}

void init() {
  // do tasks on startup
}

void loop() {
  //do looping code
}
```

With the above setup it allows my code to be even more organized.

Comment: the best answer so far +1, thanks dude you saved me!

Answer (score 5):

I would strongly prefer Method 2. If you ever plan to add code to handle input, output, etc,  it's easy with Method 2 -- just fill in `loop()`, but requires reworking/refactoring in Method 1.

Answer (score 3):

There is no time limit on the setup function. I prefer method 2 because the loop can be filled with whatever you need to later.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely go with method two. That's what the setup function is there for. It's much easier to read as well. Anything in the `loop()` implies it will be run in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

As most other answers, I would go for method 2.

But I would try to avoid the call, by Arduino library, to an an empty `loop()` that makes the Atmel consume "a lot" of current for nothing.

Edit:

As some comments pointed out though, using `delay()` in `loop()` will change nothing to power consumption.

Hence, if you would like to reduce power consumption once your `setup()` has run, you will have to play with Atmel sleep modes.
You can take a look at [this article](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/arduinoSleepCode) that shows how to deal with sleep modes from your Arduino sketches; it does more than just putting the Atmel to sleep but it is a good (and simple) read if you want to play with sleep modes.